# React: Why arent CSS animations triggered when modifying className prop elements with the same key?

Tags: css, reactjs

### Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/pkn15wl0xq

### Expected Behavior

Clicking on both side buttons should result in a Carousel like animated transition.

### Actual Behavior

Only the left button click results in correct transitions. Right button clicks just render the new color without animation.

### Details

CSSTransitions are located in `public/CSSTransitions.css`. When manually added to an elements class property using the debugger, the animation behavior is correct.

AFAIK, I have taken into account React reconciliation algorithm with the current implementation of keys. If not, please let me know.

### Relavent Code

**CSSTransitions.css**

```
.animated {
  transition: transform 1100ms cubic-bezier(0.82, 0, 0.63, 1),
    opacity 1100ms linear;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-81.8vw) translateZ(47vw) rotateY(72deg);
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.center {
  transform: translateX(0vw) translateZ(0vw) rotateY(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(81.8vw) translateZ(47vw) rotateY(-72deg);
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

**index.js**

```
const Background3D = ({ children }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      position: "fixed",
      background: "black",
      height: "100vh",
      width: "100vw",
      overflow: "visible",
      perspective: "1000px",
      transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
    }}
  >
    {children && children}
  </div>
);

const CarouselSide = ({ color, className }) => (
  <div
    className={className}
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to right,gray, ${color})`,
      position: "absolute",
      height: "inherit",
      width: "inherit",
      top: 0,
      overflow: "hidden"
    }}
  />
);

class Carousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      centerIndex: 1,
      rightTransition: false,
      leftTransition: false
    };
  }

  rotateLeft() {
    this.setState({
      centerIndex: mod(this.state.centerIndex + 1, this.props.colors.length),
      rightTransition: false,
      leftTransition: true
    });
  }

  rotateRight() {
    this.setState({
      centerIndex: mod(this.state.centerIndex - 1, this.props.colors.length),
      rightTransition: true,
      leftTransition: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Background3D>
          <CarouselSide
            key={mod(this.state.centerIndex - 1, this.props.colors.length)}
            className={this.state.leftTransition ? "animated left" : "left"}
            color={
              this.props.colors[
                mod(this.state.centerIndex - 1, this.props.colors.length)
              ]
            }
          />
          <CarouselSide
            key={this.state.centerIndex}
            className="animated center"
            color={this.props.colors[this.state.centerIndex]}
          />
          <CarouselSide
            key={mod(this.state.centerIndex + 1, this.props.colors.length)}
            className={this.state.leftTransition ? "animated right" : "right"}
            color={
              this.props.colors[
                mod(this.state.centerIndex + 1, this.props.colors.length)
              ]
            }
          />
        </Background3D>

        <CarouselButton type="left" onClick={e => this.rotateLeft()} />
        <CarouselButton type="right" onClick={e => this.rotateRight()} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Publish your relevant code to your question in addition to the offsite link, plz.

Comment: Line 86 and 100 both use leftTransition, possible line 100 requires rightTransition?

Comment: @TimHallman Good catch! Fixed that. Sorry, that was a typo. However that doesnt fix the problem.

Comment: I believe the issue is related to how you're rendering the carousel. If you remove your first carousel item you may see what I mean. You'll notice the right transition is then visible.

Comment: @TimHallman can you illustrate what you mean a tad more? And with your suggestion, would both transitions work?

Comment: If you remove your first `<CarouselSide.... />` altogether you'll see the right slide transition. Your problem has something to do with those slide layouts I believe.